# It's correct to claim that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})}}<1$?

Tags: limits

given function $f(n)$ such then: 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{f(n)}=\infty$$ 
It's correct that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ exists:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})}}=0$$ 
?

I don't have idea how to prove that. But in other hand, I can't find example that prove that it's not correct.

---

In addition, if it's not must be equal to $0$.
It's correct that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ exists:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})}}<1$$ 
?

Comment: My suspicion is that if $f$ grows sufficiently fast—perhaps $f \in \Omega(x^{\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$—then $$\liminf_{n \to +\infty} \frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})} = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take for example $f(x)=\ln(x)$ then for $k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})}}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{\ln(n^k)}{\ln(n^{k+1})}}=
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{k\ln(n)}{(k+1)\ln(n)}}=\frac{k}{k+1}.$$

As regards your second question, note that the limit (if exists) is $\leq 1$ if $f$ is increasing.

However the limit can be $>1$. For $k\geq 2$, let us define $f(n)=2\ln(n)$ if $n$ is a perfect $k$-power and $f(n)=\ln(n)$ otherwise then 
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{f(n^k)}{f(n^{k+1})}}=\frac{2k}{k+1}>1.$$

Comment: Thank you. By the way, It's will be true that this limit is smaller than $1$ (for any $f$ according to my question) ?

Comment: The limit (if exists) is $\leq 1$ if $f$ is increasing. Otherwise I think we can find a counterexample.

Comment: It's will be ok for your opinion to open a same question just with one diffenrence about "$\lim.. < 1$" ?

Comment: Are you able to edit the question and add the second question with $\leq 1$?

Comment: Yes, of course, and I ask about $\lt$ and not $\leq$

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

No, in general you cannot conclude. It is true, for instance, for $f(x)=x$, but $f(x) = \log(x)$ yields

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n^{k})}{\log(n^{k+1})} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{k\log(n)}{(k+1)\log(n)}  = \frac{k}{k+1}.$$